# Android -Adding content to bottom of ListView instead of top

Tags: android

I writing list view which must should always show message at bottom of list not at top. I want it also to auto scroll to this point whenever I add a new item. The ListView is for a chat which displays latest item at bottom of list view.  Thanks

Comment: Please add some code of how you're adding things to the listview

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried [`transcriptMode`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setTranscriptMode%28int%29)? You can also set it via the xml using `android:transcriptMode`. And here's a link to a demo from the [developer's site](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List12.html).

Comment: The Google I/O session on ListView also talks about this:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70

Answer (score 0):

Have you implemented your own version of an adapter?

Just add the required data to the dataset the adapter is based on (ArrayList in ArrayAdapter case for example) and call ArrayAdapter (or custome adapter) .`notifyDatasetChanged()`

To make a list view scroll to the bottom use the following in your activity

```
ListView myListView = getListView();
myListView.setSelection(messageAdapter.getCount() - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late maybe but for thos who wants to try..

Go on your list on the xml file and add this line

```
android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
```

This will start to add row from the bottom